# Is PHP's "Virtual Directory Support" what I think it is?

Tags: php, windows, iis

I see the entry in phpinfo(), and if it's what I think it is, then that would be great! We're on IIS and so I'm well familiar with virtual directories and have wanted that feature in PHP for a long time. Yes, I've googled it, but all I find is questions about how to enable it, but nowhere - not even on php.net - can I find a description of the feature.

So, PHP "Virtual Directory Support" is..?

Comment: Could you enlighten us on what you think it is, or are you afraid that will spoil the magic?

Comment: @IMSoP some IIS magic garbage that happens to share the same name. They are two entirely different things.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks, I don't know where to search the source for IIS, so couldn't check ;)

Answer (score 5):

*Use the source, Luke!*

Here's the relevant parts of the PHP source (from PHP 5.5, for no particular reason):

- [check of `VIRTUAL_DIR` constant that causes that line in `phpinfo` output](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/info.c#720)
- [definition of that constant based on the `ZTS` constant](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h#41)
- [decision made based on that constant in a directory called TSRM](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/TSRM/tsrm_virtual_cwd.h#250)

I believe "ZTS" stands for "Zend Thread Safety", and TSRM is the [Thread-Safe Resource Manager, documented here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.tsrm.php).

So the "virtual" here appears to mean that the Zend Engine will use its own implementations of directory access functions (including stateful ones like `cwd`) rather than directly calling the native functions provided by the underlying OS, which might not be thread-safe.

I don't know if this is what you were hoping to hear, but at least now you know :)

Comment: you made me laugh with your first answer. Yeah, terrified.

Comment: @Sammitch The IIS equivalent is what I was hoping for. And it's not garbage, it's very useful. *sigh* Ah well...a programmer can dream.

Comment: to answer your question, I was hoping it was support for IIS virtual folders. You can define a folder in your web structure and point it to any folder on the server, in the site path or not, then treat it in your code as though it _WAS_ in the site path. Very handy for common files.